# chain stop producing block after adding pallet-session

Tags: pallet, parachain, validator, session

I'm working on the pow substrate chain with grandpa. For that I integrate the pallet-session and substrate-validator-set[https://github.com/gautamdhameja/substrate-validator-set/tree/master] to join the grandpa validators on running chain. But after adding these, If I run my chain locally it get stop after 19 blocks.

Possible cause:

```rust
parameter_types! {
    pub const Period: u32 = 2 * MINUTES;
    pub const Offset: u32 = 0;
}

impl pallet_session::Config for Runtime {
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type ValidatorId = <Self as frame_system::Config>::AccountId;
    type ValidatorIdOf = validator_set::ValidatorOf<Self>;
    type ShouldEndSession = pallet_session::PeriodicSessions<Period, Offset>;
    type NextSessionRotation = pallet_session::PeriodicSessions<Period, Offset>;
    type SessionManager = ValidatorSet;
    type SessionHandler = <opaque::SessionKeys as OpaqueKeys>::KeyTypeIdProviders;
    type Keys = opaque::SessionKeys;
    type WeightInfo = ();
}
```

If i increase the timing of `Period`  variable then it effect the timing of running chain and then stop.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this issue by removing the author inherent functionality.